# Is this subset closed under addition and scalar multiplication? $x^2+y^2-z^2=0; x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am quite aware of the fact that similar questions have been asked quite a few times, yet I still struggle to really get grasp of this concept. I have to check, whether a set is in fact a linear subspace. Namely: $$V = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R} : x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 0\}$$
I know that I have to show that this set contains the zero vector, is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. I have seen some examples simply arguing that one should take some $a,b \in V$ and add them together. This should yield something like this: $(a_1+b_1)^2 + (a_2+b_2)^2 - (a_3+b_3)^2 = 0$. However, I don't know how I show that this is actually closed under addition.

Similarly, one needs to show, that the set is closed scalar multiplication, so one might take some $a \in V$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ to show that $\lambda a_1^2+\lambda a_2^2-\lambda a_3^2 = \lambda(a_1^2+a_2^2-a_3^2)$.

It obviously contains the zero vector.

Now, how am I supposed to show it is actually closed under addition, or conversely, that it isn't, except for a counterexample?

Comment: $(0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1) \in V$ but their sum, $(1, 1, 2)$, is not in $V$.

Comment: I am not talking about examples.

Comment: @AlSneed It is a counterexample to show that the space is NOT closed under addition.

Comment: I know that is isn't closed under addition. I was specifically asking how to show that it isn't closed under addition by means other than giving a counterexample

Comment: Your set is an infinite cone :) https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2By%5E2-z%5E2%3D0

Comment: @AlSneed I think I know what you are looking for. So I have put that in the answer below.

Comment: What could possibly be a better and simpler way to show that it is not closed under addition than to provide a counterexample?

Comment: Why would you want something other than a counterexample?  Counterexamples are the best possible disproof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the issue you are facing is to see how to decide if it closed under addition from the definition. So say $u=(a,b,c)$ and $v=(p,q,r)$ such that $u,v \in V$. This means we have
\begin{align}
a^2+b^2&=c^2 \tag{1}\\
p^2+q^2&=r^2 \tag{2}
\end{align}
We want to check if $u+v \in V$. In order to do that, we want to determine if
$$(a+p)^2+(b+q)^2 = (c+r)^2?$$
So start with
\begin{align*}
(a+p)^2+(b+q)^2 &= (a^2+b^2)+(p^2+q^2)+2(ap+bq)\\
& = c^2+r^2+2(ap+bq).
\end{align*}
But this last expression NEED NOT be equal to $(c+r)^2$ unless $ap+bq=cr$. This latter condition is the reason why we cannot guarantee closure under addition, as we can find vectors for which equations (1) and (2) are satisfied but $ap+bq \neq cr$.

Case in point are the examples given above by quite a few people: $u=(a,b,c)=(1,0,1)$ and $v=(p,q,r)=(0,1,1)$. Then $ap+bq=0$, whereas $cr=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $(1,0,1),(0,1,1)\in V$. But $(1,0,1)+(0,1,1)=(1,1,2)\notin V$. So, $V$ is *not* closed under addition.

But it *is* closed with respect to multiplication by a scalar: if $x^2+y^2-z^2=0$, then$$(\lambda x)^2+(\lambda y)^2-(\lambda z)^2=\lambda^2(x^2+y^2-z^2)=0,$$and therefore $(\lambda x,\lambda y,\lambda z)\in V$.

Comment: How so? why does $(\lambda x)^2 +(\lambda y)^2 - (\lambda z)^2 = \lambda^2(x^2+y^2-z^2)$ imply, that $\lambda x, \lambda y, \lambda z$ lie in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Since $\lambda,x,y,z\in\Bbb R$, $\lambda x,\lambda y,\lambda z\in\Bbb R$.